# Changing circle colour with Earthquake time elapsed

Tags: php, filtering, mapbox

Here is the webpage I am working on www.livehazards.com/lightning

I am trying to change the circle colour so that after >24hours = red, 24hrs>48hrs orange, 48h> = Yellow

Here is that section of code:

```
        map.addLayer({
    "id": "earthquake-layer",
    "type": "circle",
    "source": "earthquakes",
    "paint": {
        'circle-color': {
                "property": "time",
                "stops": [
                    [86400000, 'red'],
                    [172800000, 'orange']
```

],
},

The problem is 17280000 (48 hours) is overriding the 24 hour earthquake colour.

How do I get it so up to 24 hours (>86400000=red) ....between 24-48 hours (>86400000<17280000) etc so it dosen't overide.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the html source code is all over the place - multiple repeated tags ( body,html,head,DOCTYPE)

Comment: Please could you answer the question if you know the asnwer, Cheers

Comment: I don't think there is enough code here to allow for an answer but I would try perhaps reversing the order of the colour arrays in the `stops` array

Comment: I tried doing that but it make no difference, it just takes 48H as the overiding one and so colours all circles...orange..

Comment: Does `Openstreetmap` have documentation available for it's api? With Google Maps you can add items with their own z-index values which allows concentric overlays ( circles etc ) to be placed atop one another. Does `Openstreetmap` have the z-index capability for layers??